# Delphi - Descobrir se a aplicação está com privilégios de administrador.

Tags: delphi, windows

Boa tarde, preciso saber se uma aplicação escrita em Delphi está sendo executada com privilégios de administrador ou não. Alguém conhece alguma forma de conseguir essa informação?

Comment: Você tem acesso ao código fonte ? Sabe em que versão do Delphi foi escrita ? Se a resposta para as 2 perguntas for negativa, você quer saber se o executável foi executado como administrador através do Sistema operacional ?

Comment: Eu qm estou escrevendo o código... kkkkk

Comment: Preciso liberar uma funcionalidade do sistema apenas quando ele for executado como administrador.

Comment: Cara, confesso que já tive que fazer isso, mas nunca encontrei uma forma "Correta". Todas as vezes eu fiz um tratamento para tentar fazer o que precisava, e caso não conseguisse, eu tratava a exceção. Posso sugerir um caso, onde eu precisava criar um registro no windows, se você quiser.

Comment: É exatamente isso que preciso, liberar uma configuração que escreve no registro do Windows quando tiver privilégios de administrador. Estou fazendo dessa forma mesmo, tento recuperar o que tenho no regedit quando abro a aplicação e caso haja alguma exceção, bloqueio a configuração. Será que existe alguma forma menos gambiarra?

Comment: Ajuda? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6261865/looking-for-delphi-7-code-to-detect-if-a-program-is-started-with-administrator-r

Comment: Funcionou!!!! Deu certo com a rotina externa **function IsUserAnAdmin(): BOOL; external shell32;** do Windows. Obrigado @VictorT.

Comment: @VictorT., Posta o exemplo do link como resposta, apenas para não perder o conteúdo, e podermos marcar a resposta como válida

Comment: Fico feliz que já deu certo. Abs

Answer (score 3):

O Windows possui uma rotina que retorna se o usuário possui as permissões de administrador, é possível acessá-la através da unit ShellAPI, declarando a rotina externa no cabeçalho da unit da seguinte maneira:

```
function IsUserAnAdmin(): BOOL; external shell32;
```

Comment: Mas ela verifica a situação do **usuário** e não do **processo** como especificado na pergunta.

Comment: Sim, do usuário que executou a aplicação.

Comment: Se ela for executada com a opção "executar como administrador" a função retorna True.